# использование формулы из QString для вычисления в double

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

У меня есть некая функция, записанная в строке:

```
QString str="29+13-1"
```

Мне бы хотелось использовать её для вычисления, а так как я пришёл из питона, то решил, что всё очень просто и написал

```
double number;
number=mainstring.toDouble();
```

и получил

```
number=0;
```

а хотел бы, чтобы Qt принял это как

```
number=29+13-1;
```

и вывел ответом

```
number=41;
```

Объясните, как такое сделать.

Comment: Что такое `mainstring`? В питоне для этого `eval` используют, а не преобразование строки в число

Comment: mainstring просто название строки. И про `eval` я знаю в C# есть `compute ` но тут то как?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35416704/4711135

Comment: Нет в C# никакого compute.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря комментарию  [Alexander Chernin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235611) я смог это сделать. Решение использовать QtScript а именно QScriptEngine отлично работает. Единственное что я бы хотел уточнить перед тем как ругаться что у вас не получается  выполнить

```
#include <QtScript/QScriptEngine>
```

как это делал я(ругался), удостоверьтесь что у вас в .pro файле прописано

```
QT+=script
```

А самое главное что при установке Qt вы установили этот самый пакет QtScript если же нет то MaintenanceTool вам в помощь. Учтите что если вы пользовались оффлайн установщиком то вам придётся либо искать где скачать и как установить пакет вручную, либо переустанавливать Qt.
Ещё раз спасибо [Alexander Chernin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235611) за его наводку на https://stackoverflow.com/a/35416704/4711135.

Comment: Должен отметить, что в актуальных версиях Qt модуль QtScript помечен как deprecated и на замену ему предлагается модуль QJSEngine, который в целом по функционалу и интерфейсу практически идентичен